# Polymer attached lifecycle on chrome is different than on firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, polymer

## Context

I have a *component* inside a *page*. Currently I am firing an event from the *component*, and adding the eventListener from the *page*'s *attached* event.

## Problem

When using firefox I have no problem, the *page* loads before the *component*, but on chrome I have the opposite scenario, the *component* loads before the *page*. This results on me adding an eventListener AFTER the *component* fires the event.

Can I force the *component* to load after the app?

## [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/6YnbjCjAXJ7PER4nV0xM?p=preview)

Works on firefox, but not on chrome:

### App

```
<link rel="import" href="x-el.html" async>

<dom-module id="x-app">
  <template>
    <x-el id="el"></x-el>
    <div hidden$="[[!detail]]">Event Detail: [[detail]]</div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-app',

      attached: function(){
        this.$.el.addEventListener('foo', () => {
          this.set('detail', 'hello')
        })
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

### Element

```
<dom-module id="x-el">
  <template>
    <div>Hello from <code>x-el</code></div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-el',
      attached: function() {
        this.fire('foo', 'hello');
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the event listener from the `ready` callback instead? Or via the page element's `listeners` object?

Comment: I tried, but the error stays the same.

Comment: Sorry, I was testing your solution. Here is a demo of what I was doing.
[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/6YnbjCjAXJ7PER4nV0xM?p=preview). You can notice that it works on firefox, but not on chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the [event listener](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events) with the page element's `listeners` object:

```
// template
<x-el id="el"></x-el>

// script
Polymer({
  is: 'x-page',
  listeners: { 'el.foo': 'onFoo' },
  onFoo: function(e) {...}
});
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3vw7QJ3jdRKCiEus1GbL?p=preview)

Or use an annotated event listener:

```
// template
<x-el on-foo="onFoo"></x-el>

// script
Polymer({
  is: 'x-page',
  onFoo: function(e) {...}
});
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mdLC0AHWo5i7ABh8PRiB?p=preview)

Comment: @SeijiHirao No problem :)